# Can a CSS selector search part of a word?

Tags: css

I need a pure CSS way to select an element based on part of an HTML attribute value. For example, I want to select this element:

```
<div data-gt="{'type':'select_me'}"></div>
```

based on the fact that the element has a `data-gt` value that contains `select`. The closest I can get is using `[data-gt~=select]` as a CSS selector, but that searches for whole words only. So if the word `select` in the HTML attribute was surrounded by spaces like `{'type':' select _me'}`, it could find it no problem, but it can't find it because it's preceded by a quote and followed by an underscore.

**Note:** The example above is a simplified version of what I want to do, so no I can't just change how the HTML attribute is generated and no I can't predict any of the surrounding data in the `data-gt` attribute.

Just curious if there is a pure CSS way to do this? I know it could be handled with Javascript, but that doesn't work for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `*` [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value
>   contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.

```css
[data-gt*="select"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-gt="{'type':'select_me'}">Select Me</div>

<div data-gt="{'type':'please_dont'}">Don't Select Me</div>
```